# How to get all coordinates along the way of a direction in mapbox from point A to b?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, directions

As shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0JSS.png) We have a start and end point forming a route
I need to get all the points(Lat,Lng) forming this route.

This is how I implemented the directions:

```js
     var directions = L.mapbox.directions();

      var directionsLayer = L.mapbox.directions.layer(directions)
          .addTo(map);

      var directionsInputControl = L.mapbox.directions.inputControl('inputs', directions)
          .addTo(map);

      var directionsErrorsControl = L.mapbox.directions.errorsControl('errors', directions)
          .addTo(map);

      var directionsRoutesControl = L.mapbox.directions.routesControl('routes', directions)
          .addTo(map);
```

Comment: You should use the directions API - https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/directions-api/

Comment: I want to get like an array of points like (lat,lng),(lat,lng),(lat,lng),(lat,lng),...
along the road drawed

Comment: Technically there are infinite number of points on a route.

What you are looking for, is called "Waypoints". The API should be able to emit that data and you should be able to draw a line string using those points.

Comment: Is there any demos or examples